# Open Alternatives to Google Prediction API

Tags: machine-learning, google-prediction

A recent announcement by Google about the [Google Prediction API](http://code.google.com/apis/predict/) sounded very interesting. It could be useful for a project that is coming up, and would probably do a better job than some custom code I was considering.

However, there is some vendor lock-in. Google retain the trained model, and could later choose to overcharge me for it. It occurred to me that there are probably open-source equivalents, if I was willing to host the training myself (I am) and live without their ability to throw hardware at the problem at a moment's notice.

Last time I looked at 3rd Party computer training code was many years ago, and there were a lot of details that needed to be carefully considered and customised for your project. Google appear to have hidden those decisions, and take care of them for you. To me, this is still indistinguishable from magic, but I would like to hear whether others can do the same.

So my question is:

What alternatives to Google Prediction API exist which:

- categorise data with supervised machine learning,
- can be easily configured (or don't need configuration) for different kinds and scales of data-sets?
- are open-source and self-hosted (or at the very least, provide you with a royalty free use of your model, without a dependence on a third party)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/)?

Comment: Looks like a good solution. Still early days (by their own admission, v0.3). They are tackling a broader range of problems than just classification.

Comment: Yes, but it looks promising as they are targeted for large scale data processing.

Answer (score 11):

[PredictionIO](http://prediction.io/) is an open source machine learning server for software developers to create predictive features, such as personalization, recommendation and content discovery.

Comment: Excellent. It is built on the Apache Mahout library (at least for the default algorithms.) Doesn't seem to support general classification, just user preference prediction.

Answer (score 3):

Have been looking recently at tools like google prediction API, one of the first ones I got put on to was [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) machine learning tool which could be worth checking out for anyone looking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but [directededge](http://www.directededge.com/) seams to be doing exactly that :)

Comment: They seem to be providing a service, like Google. It isn't self-hosted, so this isn't an answer.

Comment: Project got put on a back-burner. Maybe in another year or two - which is probably when Mahout will reach 1.0! ! :-)

Comment: It's 2015, and on version 0.10. In 40 years, we'll have the stable v1.0.

Answer (score 1):

There is good free for use service [Yandex Predictor](https://tech.yandex.ru/predictor/) with 100000/day request quota. It works for text only, supports several languages and spell correction.

You need to get free API Key, then you can use simple RESTful API. Api support JSON, XML and JSONP as output.

Unfortunately I cannot find documentation in English. You can use Google Translate.

*I can translate docs if there is some demand.*